# How nginx workers listen to the same port

Tags: nginx, web, server

After going through nginx documentation, I saw that in their tutorial they make two server blocks as following:

```
server {
  listen 192.168.1.1:80
  server_name example.org www.example.org;
}
server {
  listen 192.168.1.1:80
  server_name example.net www.example.net;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both domains point to the ip 192.168.1.1, for this in the 2 domains you set the dns record type A, example:

```
www.example.org A 192.168.1.1
www.example.net A 192.168.1.1
```

The server nginx only thing it does is serve on port 80 for any domain and shows the same page.